# SharePoint Audience event webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, audience-targeting, events

I am confused about what is the Target Audience can be? Would it be AD group or SharePoint group?

Can someone please provide some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint groups are not supported in audience targeting in SharePoint online.

> Azure AD groups (including security groups and Microsoft 365 groups) are supported with the exception of AAD dynamic groups.

**Documentation**: [Target content to a specific audience on a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81)

> Currently you can only use AD groups or Microsoft 365 groups to target audiences.

**Source**: [Audience Targeting for Quick Links Web Part in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/audience-targeting-for-quick-links-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/)